# Magento 2: How to update checkout sidebar when choose shipping radio button?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, sidebar

How to show Total section in sidebar inside shipping step of onepage checkout page when click on shipping radio button in magento 2.

By default Total section dispaly, in payment step with subtotal,tax,discount and shipping info.

I want to display total block inside shipping step when click on shipping radio button.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Not yet, i have working for testing purpose.

Comment: @Rakesh I am also looking for same thing, did you get any thing into this.

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya Not yet, I am working for learning purpose but not completed.